# How to take Screenshot of QML application without QQuickView

Tags: qt, screenshot, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I want to grab screen of my QML application. But my root QML object is `ApplicationWindow`, so I can't use `QQuickView` to show it. Instead I have to use `QQmlApplicationEngine`.
I know how to take screenshot with `QQuickView` (`QQuickWindow::grabWindow`), but don't know how to take it with `QQmlApplicationEngine`.

My `main` file:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    ApplicationData appData;
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl("qrc:///main.qml"));
    return app.exec();
}
```

`main.qml` :

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.1


ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    width: appData.screenWidth
    height: appData.screenHeight
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: mainWindowBackground
        color: "red"
        anchors.fill: parent
    } 

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `rootObjects()` and cast its result to `QQuickWindow`:

```
foreach(QObject* obj, engine.rootObjects()) {
  QQuickWindow* window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(obj);
  if (window) {
    QImage image = window->grabWindow();
    qDebug() << image;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **QObject *obj, QEvent *ev** to take screenshot as well.

**Main.cpp**

```
QObject *objekt = engine.rootObjects().first();
classObj->root_object = objekt;
app.installEventFilter(classObj);
```

**classObj.h**

```
QObject *root_object = nullptr;
bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *ev);
```

**classObj.cpp**

```
bool classObj::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *ev)
{
    QString dateInterval = QString::number(QDateTime::currentSecsSinceEpoch());

    QDir dir("Screenshots");
    if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkpath(".");

    if(ev->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress) {
        QQuickWindow *window   = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(root_object);
        window->grabWindow().save("Screenshots/Screenshot-"+dateInterval+".png");
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, ev);
}
```

this will take screenshot whenever some event happenes.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast ApplicationWindow(QML) to QQuickWindow(C++). Then, It will be easy to take screenshot.

```
void ScreenShot(QQuickWindow *widget) {
    QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(widget->grabWindow());
    QFile f("your_name.png");
    f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    if(f.isOpen()) {
        pixmap.save(&f, "PNG");
    }
```